# send data from content script to webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hello I'm trying to send data *from content-script to webpage*.

In content script I have a listener:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse("Hello, I'm from content.js")
});
```

From chrome console I tried sending a message and got the following error:
[image]

I googled a lot on this and most of them talk about messaging between `content and background`. None of them discuss messaging between `content and webpage`. Any help?

Comment: Use [standard DOM messaging via CustomEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm going through that link. Btw google pointed to many of your answers and they're extremely helpful. Thank you so much for your awesomeness:)

Comment: @wOxxOm DOM messaging worked XD Thanks again:))